# Remove llvm instruction that is unremovable

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am trying to use llvm pass to convert the `pthread_create` function call into a normal function call in the parent thread instead of child thread. A simple illustration of input and output are shown in below. However when I try to use [eraseFromParent](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#ae6b978645b8ac72d1a35e1298ffdd4f0) to remove the original `pthread_create CallInst`, it always cause segmentation fault. After some deeper dive, I find out the instruction always return `false` from [mayHaveSideEffect](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#abed538d48b9e2c2f78bd01fa7d8f1d7d). I really don't know how come removing the instruction will cause any side effect.

```
void *foo(void *args) {
  sleep(2);
}

int main() {
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, foo, NULL);
  // => foo();
  pthread_join();
}
```

Thanks for @arnt's comment. Here is precisely what I want to do. I construct a CallInst whose callee is foo function and I'll replace it with the original `pthread_create` function call.

```
for (auto &inst: main_func) { // Iterate every instructions in the main function
  if (isa<CallInst>(inst)) {
    CallInst *ci = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&inst);
    if (ci->getCalledFunction()->getName().compare("pthread_create") == 0) {
      Function *start_routine = dyn_cast<Function>(ci->getArgOperand(2));
      Value *routine_args[1] = { ci->getArgOperand(3) };
      ArrayRef<Value *> arr_ref(routine_args);

      // Create a new CallInst and insert it before the "pthread_create" call instruction
      CallInst *foo = CallInst::create(start_routine, arr_ref, "startRoutineOutput", ci);

      ci->eraseFromParent(); // Segmentation fault happens here.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your code, what's the problem, *precisely*? And BTW, if you compile LLVM with debugging and assertions, this sort of thing usually gives you a precise or helpful error message.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already add more detail in my question. I install my llvm package from Ubuntu's apt tool instead of building it by my own. Could I get these debugging information as well?

Comment: I expect, but do not know absolutely, that ubuntu's packages are built with assertions disabled, and that you have to compile LLVM from source in order to get assertions.

Comment: I already try to build clang and all the lib from llvm source. I find several strange behavior of the compiler. Everything becomes extremely slow during compiling and linking. I doubt the cause is because the LLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS of the Ubuntu package is different from mine. I set it to "all" intuitively. @arnt Do you have any idea what is the recommended setting of the config?